# Why is the dog in The Call of the Wild done with CGI?

Tags: effects, the-call-of-the-wild

In the new [*The Call of the Wild*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7504726/) film, the dog is done with CGI which makes him look very cartoonish. I noticed throughout the film that other animals are also CGI, such as a rabbit and a dog team. It seems unnecessary to me, especially for a genre of film where actual animals have been used very effectively in the past. Is there any commentary on why this decision was made to use CGI animals instead of real ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From ***Screenrant***](https://screenrant.com/call-wild-movie-dog-cgi-real-life-buck-inspiration/):

> **London's adventure novel incorporates a lot of violent scenes, particularly when it comes to the dogs.** The studio found a way to lessen the violence and scares so that they could create a family-friendly film that still hits on the themes of the classic tale. CGI and motion capture technology are getting more and more common and it most likely seemed like the easier option due to the vast reliance on animals for the movie. **It's also important to note that *The Call of The Wild* wasn't shot on location and instead, was filmed on sets and green screens.** Using CGI for Buck and the other four-legged stars were always part of the plan from the early stages of development.

Comment: That's too bad. It honestly cheapened the experience for me.